# How can i find missing values when I`m using IN operator in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have an table named country which holds all the countries and their details. I`m querying for 50 country using mysql IN operator and seems some of them are missing. For instance 8 countries are missing in the list. How could I know, what are those countries.

Suppose from the below query 'croatia' and 'liechtenstein' are not in our table and how can I get those missing details alone?

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
select * from country where name in ('belgium' , 'netherland' , 'ireland' , 'france' ,
'spain' , 'portugal' , 'italy' , 'luxembourg' , ' malta' , 'monaco' , 'russia' , 'polish' ,
'liechtenstein' , 'turkish' , 'serbia' , 'croatia' , 'romania' , 'macedonia' , 'bulgaria' ,
'finland')
```

Comment: You mean they are in the DB but while using inside in function they are not getting returned ?

Comment: No It should not be in the table. But I am passing the country list manually and I have to know the countries which are not exist in table.

Comment: maybe you can try making another table with the full country list, then do a `UNION` `EXCEPT` `INTERSECT`

Comment: Suppose from the below query 'croatia' and 'liechtenstein' is not in our table and how can i get those missing details alone.

<!-- language: lang-sql -->
select * from country where name in ('belgium' , 'netherland' , 'ireland' , 'france' , 'spain' , 'portugal' , 'italy' , 'luxembourg' , ' malta' , 'monaco' , 'russia' , 'polish' , 'liechtenstein' , 'turkish' , 'serbia' , 'croatia' , 'romania' , 'macedonia' , 'bulgaria' , 'finland')

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to make a temporary table out of your list and perform a not in maintable.column or outer join where temp.column is null.